# error handling in WPF-MVVM / disabled button

Tags: wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

I have problem with error handling in view. I use caliburn.micro and MEF.

My VM look like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShellViewModel,IDataErrorInfo
{

    #region Private members

    private User _user;
    private Dictionary<string, bool> _validProperties;
    private bool _allPropertiesValid;

    #endregion

    #region Private methods

    private void ValidateProperties()
    {
        if (_validProperties.Values.Any(isValid => !isValid))
        {
            AllPropertiesValid = false;
            return;
        }
        AllPropertiesValid = true;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        _user = new User();
        _validProperties = new Dictionary<string, bool> {{"Nick", false}, {"Password", false}};
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public bool AllPropertiesValid
    {
        get { return _allPropertiesValid; }
        set
        {
            if (_allPropertiesValid != value)
            {
                _allPropertiesValid = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("AllPropertiesValid");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IShellViewModel

    public string Nick
    {
        get { return _user.Nick; }
        set
        {
            _user.Nick = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Nick");
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return _user.Password; }
        set
        {
            _user.Password = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Password");
        }
    }

    public void EmptyLogOn()
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("LogOn on server with credential: {0}, {1}", Nick, Password));
    }

    public void LogOn(string nick, string password)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("LogOn on server with credential: {0}, {1}", nick, password));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IDataErrorInfo

    public string Error
    {
        get { return (_user as IDataErrorInfo).Error; }
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = (_user as IDataErrorInfo)[propertyName];
            _validProperties[propertyName] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? true : false;
            ValidateProperties();
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
            return error;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

If I have som error I set properties AllPropertiesValid on false. I bind this properties on Button properties IsEnabled.

So in View I have this:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding AllPropertiesValid, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Micro:Message.Attach="EmptyLogOn"
        Content="Prihlás ma"
        Width="100" 
        Height="25" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Button>
<Label Content="{Binding AllPropertiesValid}" Grid.Row="3"/>
```

But if properties AllPropertiesValid is false Button is still enabled. I check the value of AllPropertiesValid (I bind this properties on label and label content is false) is false.

What’s wrong ? Thank for advance.

EDIT: In designer is button disabled, but when is loaded window button is enable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing **MVVM** then you should be using `ICommand` (or other higher-level variants such as `CommandBase`, ...) since you need to do something when button is clicked.

In this case you bind to a command property on the ViewModel, you return false on the `CanExecute` in the command and button is disabled. Sometimes you have to call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`.

This does not explain why your code is not working. To be honest, it looks alright to me.

Comment: I use caliburn because I bind method from Service, I would’nt create new Command, I post only example.